# error:no match for ‘operator ==’，what should I do？

Tags: c++

I wanna create a function that receive 3 string-type parameters `s，oldval，newval`，using `iterator，insert and erase` to replace the `oldval` in `s` by `newval`.
When I compiler it，comes the `error ：no match for the operator == in...`.

```
string &foo(string &s,string &oldval,string &newval)
{
    string::iterator it=s.begin();
    while(it!=s.end())
    {
        if(*it==oldval)
        {
            it=s.erase(it);
            it=s.insert(it,newval);
        }
        ++it;
    }
    return &s;
}
```

Comment: You are comparing a `char` and a `string`, read you code again. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: `if(*it==oldval)` is "if(character == string)" and that makes no sense

Comment: Why would you think that a equality comparison between a char and a string would work?

Comment: BTW: The error message should list the actual types you tried to compare...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`it` is iterating over the characters of the string; `*it` is a single character. You can compare that with another character, but not with a string.

Either `oldval` and `newval` should have type `char`, not `string`; or you need more complicated logic to look for and replace substrings, rather than single characters, in the input. The member functions [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`replace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) might be helpful for that.

Note that replacing a single character is as simple as `*it = newval;`, with no need to mess around erasing and inserting characters.

Answer (score 1):

A string iterator "points" to a type of char (the template parameter for std::basic_string that makes up the std::string type), but you're comparing that character to a string (oldval) using ==.

std::string doesn't have an overload comparison operator for char.

Answer (score 0):

Viktor,

I have seen your question.
"s" is a string. Wenn you use pointer,pointer only points a character. That means, just one character is selected. How can you compare a character with a string? Compiler will tell you,
"no match for the operator == in..." .
You need to view the website:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Best regards

Dehlen Zhang

Comment: thank you！ BTW，character can be a word？or just a letter？this makes me confused.sorry I know the question is silly.